# How to limit 'related product' in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am showing related products in magento2 in `Product description page` . And this is I guess due to these lines in code in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
 <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" >
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" />

            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

And It is showing on front page like this 
[image: related products]

So I want now that Can I remove its slider and show only 2 products all time ?

How it is possible to do that ? I am using infornite theme

Comment: You have using Infotis theme,Please check it setting

Comment: @AmitBera  which settings ?

Comment: @AmitBera which files you are talking ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to limit the upsell products on product view page :

1. Overide the Magento_Catalog's Block using a custom module

Create a custom module and create a di.xml(CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml) file in it.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related">
         <plugin name="CompanyName_ModuleName_plugin" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Related" sortOrder="0" />
     </type>
 </config>
```

Create CompanyName/ModuleName/Block/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Related.php

```
 <?php
 namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

 /**
  * Class Related
  *
  * @package CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Plugin\Product\ProductList
  */
 class Related
 {
     /**
      * Add limit to related product collection if page_size argument is defined
      *
      * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $subject
      * @param $result
      *
      * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
      */
     public function afterGetItems(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $subject, $result)
     {
         $pageSize = 3;
         $collection = $result;

         if ($pageSize) {
             $collection->getSelect()->limit($pageSize);
         }

         return $collection;
     }
 }
```

2. Second method is override the items.phtml file

Copy items.phtml into your theme like app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Line No. 62 replace below code:

```
 $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
 to
 $limit = 3;

 and Line No. 82 replace below code:

 $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell'); 
 to
 $limit = 3;
```

Comment: is it for ultimo theme or luma ?

Comment: Either, its a method to override and get the result as needed

Comment: I think its for upsell ? ?? I want for related products actually

Comment: and items.phtml of which module I have to copy?

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Comment: check line no. 62 and replace

 $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
 to
 $limit = 3;

Comment: sir case:related  is looking like this somehow .

Comment: if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showAddTo = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
        }

Comment: Still same output

Comment: Check once doing change in core file and run below command

`1. php bin/magento cache:clean
2. php bin/magento cache:flush
3. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
5. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
6. chmod 777 -R var/*
7. chmod 777 -R pub/*
8. rm -rf pub/static/*`

If its works then it is issue with overriding flow

Comment: still coming in same way :( .

Comment: Can I change   'grid12-8' to 'grid12-6 ' ?  it seems maybe due to lack of space its happening in row?